# Como adicionar AsyncTask nessa tarefa?

Tags: java, android, asynctask, volley

Olá, alguem poderia me ajudar a adiconar um AsyncTask nessa tarefa?
Aqui estou me conectando a um JSON para obter informações, em seguida elas serão adicionadas no RecyclerView.

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String shhik = "http://meusite/arquivo.json";
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, shhik, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Response " + response);
                GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
                Gson mGson = builder.create();
                List<receive_info> posts = new ArrayList<receive_info>();
                posts = Arrays.asList(mGson.fromJson(response, receive_info[].class));
                adapter = new adapter_info(Main.this, posts);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Erro ao tentar conectar com servidor!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d(TAG, "Error " + error.getMessage());
            }
        });
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Muito obrigado!

Comment: Por que quer adicionar uma AsyncTask? `queue.add(stringRequest);` já executa o *request* de forma assíncrona.

Comment: @ramaral Olá amigo! Obrigado por responder. Então, quero adicionar uma AsyncTask, pra eu mostrar para o usuario um progressBar, AlertDialog..

Answer (score 3):

Não precisa de adicionar uma *AsyncTask* para poder mostrar um *ProgressBar*.
O *Volley* processa o *request* de forma assíncrona.

Nessa perspectiva e por comparação à *AsyncTask*, o método `onResponse()`, ou o `onErrorResponse()` caso haja um erro, corresponde ao método `onPostExecute()`.
O que colocar antes de `queue.add(stringRequest);` "corresponde" a ser colocado no `onPreExecute()`.

Assim, deve iniciar o *ProgressBar* na linha anterior a `queue.add(stringRequest);` e terminá-lo nos métodos `onResponse()` e `onErrorResponse()`.